# MSSQL database connection in plesk

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, somee

I have tried to host my asp.net web site in a free hosting [somee.com](http://somee.com) and it works perfectly with the database.

The problem is, now I want to host it in another server and i make the same steps as done in the first one, but the connection between my website and the database is not working.

The question is: Is there a problem with the configuration of the new server OR the problem is in my code?
ps: I'm using plesk in the new server.

Comment: We have no idea. You haven't provided any info. Whats the error? WHats the connection string?

Comment: the error is :Error.

An error occurred while processing your request./String connection:Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=admin_;Integrated Security=False;User ID=****;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096

Comment: Not even sure what "plesk" or a "serveur" is. This site is for programming questions, if you need help with server configuration you should ask in Server Fault or get help from your hoster

Comment: You need to dig into the logs and find a more descriptive error then edit your question and add this information

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform some steps for the connection string,

Step 1:
Connect your mssql with you host provided database (by giving all the credentials)
Step 2:
Then By Using Entity Frame work connect your self with that database that you already imported in your local mssql .Entity frame work will embed the connection string automatically in your web.config file.